# MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: go, mime-types, gorilla, mux

I was using golang net/http funcions and had no errors, but I needed custom URL so I implemented gorilla/mux router and now getting errors like this:

```
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/styles.css” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/main.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
The resource from “http://localhost:8080/base.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

code before:

```golang
http.Handle("/transcode", http.HandlerFunc(transcodeHandler))
http.Handle("/tctype", http.HandlerFunc(tctypeHandler))
http.Handle("/sse/dashboard", lp.B)
http.Handle("/upload", http.HandlerFunc(uploadHandler))
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("views")))
fmt.Println("Listening on port: 8080...")
log.Fatalf("Exited: %s", http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

code after:

```golang
r := mux.NewRouter()

r.Handle("/ngx/mapping/{name}", http.HandlerFunc(ngxMappingHandler))
r.Handle("/transcode", http.HandlerFunc(transcodeHandler))
r.Handle("/tctype", http.HandlerFunc(tctypeHandler))
r.Handle("/sse/dashboard", lp.B)
r.Handle("/upload", http.HandlerFunc(uploadHandler))
r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("views")))
fmt.Println("Listening on port: 8080...")
log.Fatalf("Exited: %s", http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r))
```

Comment: Please provide a short, self-contained example. For example, you do not specify the implementation of `ngxMappingHandler`.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary because ```ngxMappingHandler``` works fine after I added gorilla/mux, but css and javascript files does not load.

Comment: I am getting the same issue while using react js and ajax-solr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed this line:

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("views")))
```

Into this:

```
r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("views"))))
```

Comment: Why does this work?